# move vim cursor after a function

Tags: vim, autocomplete, snipmate

I'm using both the supertab and snipmate plugins. Let's say I'm using snipmate to create an if statement structure. Once I'm done adding statements inside the if-statement, how can I quickly move the cursor after the if-statement. For example:

```
if [ $a = "b" ]; then
  bla;
fi
```

If my cursor is right on the semicolon and I'm in insert mode. What is the fewest number of actions I can take to move the cursor to the line after the 'fi'? If I press tab, supertab just open an autocomplete window.

Thanks

Comment: If your code is on one line like that, <ctrl-o>A would do it, same with <ctrl-o>G if you're at the end of the file; but since those aren't nominal cases I'm not leaving it as an answer.

Comment: My mistake. The code actually spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using snipMate I'd suggest modifying the snippet for your file type. For instance the example you give looks to me to be something like a shell script snippet. In that case then I'd modify YOUR-VIM-CONFIGURATION-FOLDER/snippets/sh.snippets to us a definition like the following (adding an additional TAB variable at the end of the snippet):

```
snippet if
  if [ ${1:condition} ]; then
    ${2:#statements}
  fi
  ${3}
```

snipMate will then allow you to use the TAB and SHIFT-TAB keys to move back and forth between the condition, statements and end of the if block.

Answer (score 2):

Non sure about the plugins (I don't use them, but in regular vim):

```
<Esc>
/fi$
o
```

The $ sign might be superfluous most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Just press `C-o o`

Answer (score 0):

I would press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to start insert mode on the next line. But perhaps you could reconfigure snipmate so that you can press some other key instead of <kbd>tab</kbd> to finish the snippet?

If you haven't mapped it, the <kbd>down</kbd> arrow key should also move the cursor to the next line.